# Pandas remap to range in column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame with a colum with id:s, can contain duplicates:

```
>>> df['user_id'].head()
Out[3]: 
0    2134
1    1234
2    4323
3    25434
4    1234
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
```

How can I remap this so that the user id's goes from an arbitrary number and up, incrementally according to the original number? In this example it will be the following, starting from 2:

```
>>> df['user_id'].head()
Out[3]: 
0    3
1    2
2    4
3    5
4    2
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to sort the df by the values in that column, first and then use `factorize`:

```
In [29]:
df1 = df.reindex(df['user_id'].sort_values().index)
df1

Out[29]:
       user_id
index         
1         1234
4         1234
0         2134
2         4323
3        25434

In [30]:    
df1['new_id'] = pd.factorize(df1['user_id'])[0] + 2
df1

Out[30]:
       user_id  new_id
index                 
1         1234       2
4         1234       2
0         2134       3
2         4323       4
3        25434       5
```

You can then restore the index using `sort_index`:

```
In [31]:
df1 = df1.sort_index()
df1

Out[31]:
       user_id  new_id
index                 
0         2134       3
1         1234       2
2         4323       4
3        25434       5
4         1234       2
```

You can then either overwrite or drop a column, the above is just to demonstrate how to get the values you want

Comment: Cool! If I don't care about the index or saving the the old ids it's simply to do this, right?
df1['user_id'] = pd.factorize(df1['user_id'])[0]

Comment: @user1506145 sure or call `reset_index(drop=True)` to just have the index start again from `0`

Answer (score 0):

the question is kind of confusing.. i am not sure if you want to increase the user id by an arbitrary number or if you want to just show user ids above a certain threshold... so i will give a solution to both:

> df['user_id'].map(lambda x: x+2) will give you the user_ids +2
>
> df.loc[df['user_id']>2] will return you only user_ids higher than 2

if you want to sort the user ids you can:

> df['user_id'].sort_values()

hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but neither. I want to remap the user id:s, so that they start at 2 and goes up incrementally by one. Look at the sample output :)