# Remap array of integers to range in NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume I have a numpy array of integers (can be both positive or negative and contain duplicates) like so:

`arr = array([-23, 1983, 2344, 323, -34, 323, -234432, 22343])`

Now I want to create a new array `arr_remapped`, so that all integers get a new number (from zero) according to their size in the array like so:

`arr_remapped = array([2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 6])`

The `arr_remapped` will contain numbers in the range `[0, number_of_unique_numbers-1]`, and can contain duplicates.

How to do this using only NumPy (or perhaps Scikit-learn) in a few lines of code?

It's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808839/pandas-remap-to-range-in-column) question, but I only want to use NumPy instead here.

Answer (score -1):

There's a function in NumPy for that: `argsort`.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html

Comment: if the list has no duplicates yes, but he said that it could contain duplicates and they should have the same number.